# Chazan forgot Yaaleh VeYavo at Maariv Chol HaMoed

Tags: halacha, tefilla, chol-hamoed

If a Chazan forgets Yaaleh Veyovo at Shacharis or Mincha - Shulchan Aruch HaRav 126:3-4 says that the Chazan can rely on his repetition of the Shemona Esrei for the forgotten Yaaleh Veyavo. If I am not mistaking this is the way Ashkenazim rule. (I do not know if the Sefardim rule the same or different).

What should a Chazan who is Davening Maariv on Chol Hamoed (when if Yaaleh Veyavo is forgotten one has to ray again) and forgot to say Yaaleh Veyavo do?

A: Repeat Shemona Esrei and make the Tzibur wait.

B: Say Kaddish and Aleinu and then say over Shemona Esrei.

C: Something else.

Sources please.

Comment: I can't imagine how A would be appropriate. We even let a Chazzan who forgot at Shacharit just rely on Musaf so as not to delay the Tzibbur!

Comment: Why should it be any different to what any other member of the congregation does? Finish davening and then go back and do it privately, yourself.

Comment: @GershonGold - Is that a rule? I'm not aware of that. If it is, and if there are no two ways around it, then maybe somebody else needs to say the kaddish and step in as chazzan?

Comment: Based on Double AA above, the chazan Shachris who relies on Musaf, is also saying a kaddish. The fact that the Maariv chazan has not yet corrected his omission does not go so far as to say he never davened with the tzibur. He did pray a whole amidah with them. We have no reason to disqualify his kaddiah just because he needs to perfect his prayer later.

Comment: For the shmona esre the repetition is the true tfila of the chazan. When there is no repetition he is exactly as a yachid. He needs to make shmona esre afterwards with an other minyan. To make tircha detsibura is a great sin

Comment: I've always been taught (Ashkenazi tradition) exactly how you describe in the first paragraph, as well as option B. I don't have a source in the poskim, though.

Comment: What about Shabbos Chol Hamoed when you do have a mini chazarat hashatz?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This question (in the context of forgetting morid hageshem) was posed to Rabbi Efraim Grenblatt in his sefer Rivevos Efraim ([volume 1 responsum 177](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1081&pgnum=134)). Rabbi Greenblatt cites the sefer Oreach Ne'eman (Rabbi Menachem Aeurbach, Jerusalem 1926) who is of the opinion that someone else shall say the kaddish. The son of the author, Rabbi Yitzchok Aeurbach in a footnote disagrees with his father and says the chazzon says the kaddish and he repeats the shemona esraei after aleinu.
Rabbi Greenblatt also quotes Rabbis Seraya Deblitzki of Bnei Brak who agrees with Rabbi Yitzchok Auerbach.

Rabbi Avrohom Yeshaya Phefer in his sefer Ishei Yisroel page 271 footnote 177 writes that Rabbi Chaim Kanievski responded to him in writing like the opinion of 
Rabbi Deblitzki.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Thanks for the answer!